# Was following the ReactJS tutorial and was wondering about expanding on what it teaches

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I want to do with the tutorial now that I've gone though it is to add a time stamp to each of the comments when they are posted to the page. Can anyone help me?

Here's the code I have so far that's the main JS file.

```js
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {author: '', text: ''};
  },

  handleAuthorChange: function(e){
    this.setState({author: e.target.value});
  },

  handleTextChange: function(e){
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },

  handleSubmit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var author = this.state.author.trim();
    var text = this.state.text.trim();
    if(!text || !author) {
      return;
    }
      this.props.onCommentSubmit({author: author, text: text});
      this.setState({author: '', text: ''});

  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name"
               value={this.state.author}
               onChange={this.handleAuthorChange}
        />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Say Something..."
               value={this.state.text}
               onChange={this.handleTextChange}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="post" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>

    );
  }
});



var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  loadCommentsFromServer: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err){
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  handleCommentSubmit: function(comment){
    var comments = this.state.data;
    comment.Id = Date.now();
    var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
    this.setState({data: newComments});

    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data){
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err){
        this.setState({data: comments});
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },



  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },

  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox url='/api/comments' pollInterval={2000}/>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Here is the server.js file.

```js
/**
 * This file provided by Facebook is for non-commercial testing and evaluation
 * purposes only. Facebook reserves all rights not expressly granted.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
 * FACEBOOK BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN
 * ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
 * WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var COMMENTS_FILE = path.join(__dirname, 'comments.json');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Additional middleware which will set headers that we need on each request.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Set permissive CORS header - this allows this server to be used only as
    // an API server in conjunction with something like webpack-dev-server.
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Disable caching so we'll always get the latest comments.
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    next();
});

app.get('/api/comments', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(COMMENTS_FILE, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    res.json(JSON.parse(data));
  });
});

app.post('/api/comments', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(COMMENTS_FILE, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    var comments = JSON.parse(data);
    // NOTE: In a real implementation, we would likely rely on a database or
    // some other approach (e.g. UUIDs) to ensure a globally unique id. We'll
    // treat Date.now() as unique-enough for our purposes.
    var newComment = {
      id: Date.now(),
      author: req.body.author,
      text: req.body.text,
    };
    comments.push(newComment);
    fs.writeFile(COMMENTS_FILE, JSON.stringify(comments, null, 4), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
      res.json(comments);
    });
  });
});


app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Server started: http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '/');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Saving the timestamp on the server

Whenever you save a comment, you will need to add a timestamp to the saved data. In server.js, we can modify our comment-save handler to add a timestamp:

```
app.post('/api/comments', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(COMMENTS_FILE, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    var comments = JSON.parse(data);
    // NOTE: In a real implementation, we would likely rely on a database or
    // some other approach (e.g. UUIDs) to ensure a globally unique id. We'll
    // treat Date.now() as unique-enough for our purposes.
    var newComment = {
      id: Date.now(),
      author: req.body.author,
      text: req.body.text,
      timestamp: new Date()  // Add timestamp to saved comment
    };
    comments.push(newComment);
    fs.writeFile(COMMENTS_FILE, JSON.stringify(comments, null, 4), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
      res.json(comments);
    });
  });
});
```

### Displaying the timestamp in the UI

Ok sweet, now we're saving a timestamp whenever a comment is saved. We now need to update our UI to display this data:

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        {this.props.children}
        <span>Created on: {this.props.timestamp}</span>
      </div>

    );
  }
});
```

Our Comment component is now expecting a timestamp property to be passed as a prop. We need to update our CommentList component to pass this data:

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author}
            key={comment.id}
            timestamp={comment.timestamp}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

And now we will display the timestamp for each saved comment! If you want to format the timestamp, I'd recommend using a date helper library like moment: http://momentjs.com/